# Is there a way to read duration type field from excel with Python openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to read duration field from Excel file, but instead of timedelta type I get datetime type. So when duration value is more than 24 hours, python openpyxl reads that field not correctly. Is there a right way to read duration field with Python openpyxl?

```
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('./files/file.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.active

cell = worksheet.cell(row=2, column=9)
print(cell.value)
```

Cell (row=2, column=9) value in excel file is 38:12:40, but printed output:

1900-01-01 14:12:40

Cell format code in excel file - [HH]:MM:SS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this solution will work for you, maybe you need to adjust the format but the type is timedelta

```
cell = worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1)
print(cell.value) #1900-01-01 14:12:40
s = cell.value-datetime.datetime(1899,12,30)
print(s) #2 days, 14:12:40
print(type(s)) #<class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

The problem is that Excel have a custom type and when you put that format, it will convert it for that one starting in 1900

Comment: I tried to add data_only=True, but nothing changed. There are no formula in excel file, cells have [HH]:MM:SS format and I write values there by hand or other parts of code (writing timedelta type values). If cell's value is <24hours, I get time type field, if >24hours - I get datetime type field.