# Difference Python on Windows & Linux: datetime.datetime object has no attribute total_seconds

Tags: python, linux, windows, datetime

A python script I developed in Linux works fine in Linux. It uses openpyxl to iterate over cells in an Excel-file, compares values to lists, and calculates total time spent by adding different timedelta objects (in total seconds). So far so good...

But the script does not work on my Windows laptop I use for work. Installed is Python 3.8.5. The error I get is:

```
File "Worktypes", line 54, in <module>
    ndcluren += int(f.total_seconds())
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'total_seconds
```

The original code in the script is:

```
for j in range(6):
    facturen = 0
    decluren = 0
    ndcluren = 0
    resturen = 0
    
    for i in range(5,30):
        e = sheet2.cell(row = i, column = 1).value
        f = sheet2.cell(row = i, column = j+5).value
        if f:
            if e in fact:
                facturen += int(f.total_seconds())
            elif e in decl:
                decluren += int(f.total_seconds())
            elif e in ndcl:
                ndcluren += int(f.total_seconds())
            else:
                resturen += int(f.total_seconds())
    
    sheet4.cell(row = 2, column = j+3).value = facturen / 3600
    sheet4.cell(row = 3, column = j+3).value = decluren / 3600
    sheet4.cell(row = 4, column = j+3).value = ndcluren / 3600
    sheet4.cell(row = 5, column = j+3).value = resturen / 3600
```

What is somewhat surprising is that the script handles total_seconds() fine for the "facturen" and the "decluren", but then fails for the ndcluren. This makes me think that the error is in the excel spreadsheet. But I cannot find anything strange or special. Changing the cell formatting also doesn't work.

I already spent quite some hours on this. Indications from Google indicate that the script uses python2 instead of python3. But also after forcing python3 I get this error on Windows.

**Solved**

It turns out there are two issues at play.

1. **First issue**
   Excel registers duration times as a date. The cell displays 30:30 (30 hours and 30 minutes) but in the formula edit field in Excel this shows as "1-1-1900  06:30:00". [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874619/is-there-a-way-to-read-duration-type-field-from-excel-with-python-openpyxl) gives the answer to this issue.
2. **Second issue**
   Some cells are recognized as datetime.time objects and some are recognized as datetime.datetime objects. In case of datetime.time objects the above solution does not work. I solved this by adding a date to the time object, and combine the date and time into a datetime object. The new script works as expected:

```
for j in range(6):
    facturen = 0
    decluren = 0
    ndcluren = 0
    resturen = 0
    
    for i in range(5,30):
        naam = sheet2.cell(row = i, column = 1).value
        cell = sheet2.cell(row = i, column = j+5)
        if cell.value:
            if isinstance(cell.value, datetime.time):
                date = datetime.datetime.strptime('1899-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
                s = datetime.datetime.combine(date, cell.value)
                s = s-datetime.datetime(1899,12,31)
            else:
                s = cell.value-datetime.datetime(1899,12,31)
            if naam in fact:
                facturen += int(s.total_seconds())
            elif naam in decl:
                decluren += int(s.total_seconds())
            elif naam in ndcl:
                ndcluren += int(s.total_seconds())
            else:
                resturen += int(s.total_seconds())
    
    sheet4.cell(row = 2, column = j+3).value = facturen / 3600
    sheet4.cell(row = 3, column = j+3).value = decluren / 3600
    sheet4.cell(row = 4, column = j+3).value = ndcluren / 3600
    sheet4.cell(row = 5, column = j+3).value = resturen / 3600
```

Still don't understand why in Windows needs extra lines of code, and python on Linux does not. But at least my issue is solved

Comment: Could you tell me exactly what you have imported at the top of your file?

Comment: Please edit the code in your question to be a [mre] - including imports

Answer (score 1):

[`total_seconds()` is an instance method of `timedelta` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds), not `datetime` objects. It might be that your spreadsheet "ndcluren" duration cells are not set up correctly for `openpyxl` to handle them; see the [Handling timedelta values](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datetime.html#handling-timedelta-values) section of the `openpyxl` documentation for more information.

Comment: Oh, it was timedelta and not datetime. Thanks XD